# I need to predict the counts of ticket in coming years and the data I have are:

Tags: prediction

I need to predict the counts of ticket in coming years and the data I have are:
1.Month
2.Counts for previous years
3.Domains on which the tickets were raised.

I used input features as Month and Domains and Counts as Labels.
I am using Linear model.Since, I am a rookie in this field, I would like to know whether I am going right or not?
(NOTE:I have created dummies for the domain.For months, I have used numbers from 1-12)

Can anyone please guide me on the same?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to predict **counts**, you should use [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression), [quasi-Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#Overdispersion_and_zero_inflation) or [negative binomial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/) regression. Linear models can predict any value in $(-\infty, \infty)$. Negative values don't make a great deal of sense when you're talking about counts!